# update-grub does not see another linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I've installed Gentoo from Ubuntu on `/dev/sda4` using [this tutorial, which uses Ubuntu instead of LiveCD](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Gentoo-Linux-from-Ubuntu).

But tutorial did not have anything about updating GRUB.

So I did it as usual:

```
sudo update-grub
```

The output looked like this:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Found Gentoo Base System release 2.2 on /dev/sda4
done
```

(note it did see Gentoo).

But when I reboot, Grub does not show Gentoo option.

Also, file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` does not have Gentoo option.

Tried `boot-repair` (Ubuntu program for updating GRUB). Same thing.

Most probably I screwed something up with Gentoo, but just to be sure - am I missing anything on Ubuntu side? Like some command, I have to run after `update-grub`?

Oh, and I don't want to make Gentoo my main OS for now. Just trying it out.

Comment: Can you manually boot Gentoo from GRUBs shell? Read [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/), if you don't know how.

Comment: Does running `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` help? That should write the new configuration to your disk (**assuming that grub is installed at `/dev/sda`**).

Comment: Do you have a /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new? That would indicate that something has a typo. Perhaps something in Gentoo's grub that Ubuntu's grub is copying is not correct format? Extra quote or missing { or } can cause issues. You can also try copying Gentoo's boot stanza to 40_custom to see if it works, but check format/style to be sure it is what grub2 likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with careful Gentoo recompile & `update-grub`.